# How can I edit my httpd.conf file?

Tags: command-line, sudo, gedit

I have XAMPP installed, and need to edit my `httpd.conf` file to add a virtual host block. If I right-click on the file in Nautilus and open with *gedit*, I can see all the content, but it's read-only.

If I try to open it via terminal, like this:

```
esther@estherLinuxSony:~$ sudo gedit opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

It opens the root version of gedit, but there's no content in the file.

How can I edit this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the slash before 'opt', the following should work:

```
gksudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify what the difference is between sudo and gksudo? It seems to work either way.

Comment: gksudo will open a graphical dialog to prompt you for your password, while sudo will do it in the terminal.

Comment: See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo